# Why can't I seem to get this reoccuring loop to work?

Tags: java

Here is link to the problem I am working on: http://programmingbydoing.com/a/adventure2.html

I cannot seem to get it to the downstairs area. We are supposed to use mainly while and if loops, so if there is a possibility to from one area of the loop to the other, that would be great to hear input!

```
public class Adventure2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int nextroom = 1;
        String choice = "";

        System.out.println("MITCHELL'S TINY ADVENTURE 2!");
        System.out.println("")

        while (nextroom != 0) {
            if (nextroom == 1) {
                System.out.println("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go to the \"kitchen\" or \"upstairs\"?");
                System.out.print("> ");
                choice = keyboard.next();

                if (nextroom == 1) {
                    System.out.println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere.  Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the \"refrigerator\" or go \"back\".");
                    choice = keyboard.next();
                    if (choice.equals("back")) {
                        System.out.println("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go to the \"kitchen\" or \"upstairs\"?");
                        System.out.println("> ");
                        choice = keyboard.next();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The refrigerator falls on you.");

                        if (nextroom == 2) {
                            System.out.println("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go to the \"kitchen\" or \"upstairs\"?");
                            System.out.println("> ");
                            choice = keyboard.next();
                            if (choice.equals("upstairs")) {
                                System.out.println("Upstairs you see a hallway.  At the end of the hallway is the master \"bedroom\".  There is also a \"bathroom\" off the hallway. Or you can go back \"downstairs\". Where would you like to go?");
                                System.out.println("> ");
                                choice = keyboard.next();
                                if (choice.equals("downstairs")) {
                                    System.out.println("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go to the \"kitchen\" or \"upstairs\"?");

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You can only go downstairs after going upstairs.

Comment: Is this a request for the `goto` statement?  Splitting it into separate methods (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) may help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly your code is a bit of a mess, but that's not unusual for a beginner.

The trick is to carefully read the code that you have written, and to "run it in your head".  In your example, you will come to this point:

```
        System.out.println("You are in a creepy house!...");
        System.out.print("> ");
        choice = keyboard.next();
```

You read a choice.  But what happens next?  What do you do with that choice?  Answer .... nothing!  Here's what you do next.

```
        if (nextroom == 1) {
            System.out.println("There is a long countertop ...;
            choice = keyboard.next();
```

You have ignored the first `choice` you read, you test `nextroom` again (which won't have changed because you didn't assign anything new to it.

If you read your code carefully and try to run it in your head (like a computer does), then these problems *should* leap out at you.  If that's too hard, then using a debugger will help.

That brings us back to my original comment.  When you start getting your head around what *should* be happening, you should realise that there *general* pattern that your program should follow.  Something like this

```
 while (not finished):
     print description of where I am
     print choices of where to go next next
     get choice
     if choice is valid:
         change location
     else:
         print error message
```

If you do it right, you should not need to copy-and-paste the pattern in the loop body multiple times.

- Hint: think about using array and array indexing.
- Hint 2: `nextroom` could be used as an array index.